# Can someone explain this rewrite in plain english

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I have a domain and have been hosting several subdomains as well. The environment was setup pretty barebones by the provider and I have full access to make whatever changes I deem fit. I need to understand what this rewrite thing is doing so that I can learn and fix the issue of everything being sent to /homepage regardless of address people type in the bar.

```
RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/homepage
```

Ideally results would be that a user types http://domain.tld and get https://domain.tld or they type https://domain.tld and get what they typed. or type http://sub.domain.tld and get https://sub.domain.tld.

also ideally only domain.tld and https://domain.tld should be sent to https://domain.tld/homepage

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
#This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
#This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/homepage 
#This will send all requests to specified address, in this case homepage
```

The RewriteCond defines the condition under which the rewriting will takes place. In other words the execution of the RewriteRule

Check this [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html) for more information